# Error : 'The instance of entity type 'Produtos' cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0, in-memory-database

Hello I'm trying to add a list of products to my order but I'm getting the exception in my C# code: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Products' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1} ' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.' I tried some solutions but I couldn't solve the problem.I am using for my test application inMemoryDatabase.

```
 public class Pedidos
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public List<Produtos> ProdutosPedido { get; set; }
    }

public class Produtos
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public int FornecedorId { get; set; }

        public Fornecedores Fornecedores { get; set; }

        public int TributacaoId { get; set; }

        public Tributacoes Tributacoes { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public Pedidos Adicionar(Pedidos pedido)
        {
            _dbContext.Pedido.Add(pedido);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges(); //error here
            return pedido;
        }
```

```
 {
    "id": 2,
    "descricao": "Pedido 1",
    "valor": 52.36,
    "dataCriacao": "2023-08-25T08:59:59.4587309-03:00",
    "produtosPedido": [ //class produto
      {
        "id": 1,
        "descricao": "Teste Produto",
        "fornecedorId": 1,
        "tributacaoId": 1,
      }
    ]
  }
```

```
public class EFDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFDBContext(DbContextOptions<EFDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<TipoDespesas> TipoDespesa { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fornecedores> Fornecedor { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tributacoes> Tributacao { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Produtos> Produto { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pedidos> Pedido { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("BC-Teste");
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }
    }
```

I already tried to modify the product state.

Comment: Is the class 'Products' or 'Produtos'?

Comment: The class is Orders which has adds a list of Products. But the error happens when adding the order itself.

Comment: I can't tell what is happening with the code posted.  The error indicates you have a primary key ID and I cannot tell what tables/classes use the key.  I also do not know the type of database you are using (just in-memory).  Not all types of database can be shared.  To prevent conflict in multi-user databases there are locks to prevent the same resource from be used twice.  For example if there is 10 items in stock and one request want 8 items and second request want 5 items you do not want to take 13 items from stock.

Comment: Where do you get `Pedido` from before you add it? If you get it from the database you will get an object that has its changes tracked by EntityFramework. My question would then be why would you get an item and then add it? I already exists why would you need to add it?

Comment: In my front end the user can include more than one product in the order, but when adding Order in the bank it gives the mentioned exception. The data model that comes from the front is the json mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try adding a `Pedido` without an Id, this must be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then modify your code in this way:

```
public Pedidos Adicionar(Pedidos pedido)
{
    foreach (var produto in pedido.ProdutosPedido)
    {
        _dbContext.Attach(produto);
    }
    _dbContext.Pedido.Entry(pedido).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return pedido;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because your Pedidos object that you are trying to add is considered as the same instance as one existing in your database.

I would suggest your to use **"AsNoTracking()"** when you are retrieving your **Pedidos** object

Like that

```
public async Task<Pedidos> GetPedidos(int id){
Pedidos pedido= await _context.Pedidos
    .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
return pedido;
}
```